# CXF return list of elements

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs

This works fine:

```
@GET
@Path("elements")
public List<Element> getElements(@HeaderParam(SESSION_TOKEN) String token) {
    try {
        if (token != null) {
            Session session = new Session();
            if (session.initWithToken(token)) {
                ElementFacade sf = ElementFacade.getInstance();
                return sf.getElements(session.getUser());
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        log.error("", th);
    }
    return new ArrayList<Element>();
}
```

I get a very nice JSON array with objects.

The Problem is now I like to put my data as payload into a Response, to be able to set headers and status and to alternatively return an error object as payload.
But it doesn't work.

```
@GET
@Path("elements2")
public Response getElements2(@HeaderParam(SESSION_TOKEN) String token) {
    try {
        if (token == null) {
            return ResponseFactory.createResponse(401, 4007);
        }
        Session session = new Session();
        if (session.initWithToken(token)) {
            ElementFacade sf = ElementFacade.getInstance();
            return Response.status(200)
                    .header(Endpoint.SESSION_TOKEN, session.getToken())
                    .entity(sf.getElements(session.getUser())).build();
        }
        return ResponseFactory.createResponse(403, 4006);
    } catch (InvalidTokenException e) {
        return ResponseFactory.createResponse(401, 4005);
    } catch (SessionTimeoutException e) {
        return ResponseFactory.createResponse(401, 4004);
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        log.error("", th);
        return ResponseFactory.createResponse(500, 5099);
    }
}
```

Mai 16, 2012 7:00:35 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor writeResponseErrorMessage
Warnung: No message body writer has been found for response class ArrayList.

How can I user the same existing functionality that works for the first function in the second function?

I read something about writing an own MessageBodyWriter but in that class I need to write the whole JSON into an OutputStream and seems to be a lot work and overhead...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so damn easy. But haven't found it in any documentation...

I tried a lot and then baammm...

```
@GET
@Path("elements2")
public Response getElements2(@HeaderParam(SESSION_TOKEN) String token) {
      try {
          if (token == null) {
              return ResponseFactory.createResponse(401, 4007);
          }
          Session session = new Session();
          if (session.initWithToken(token)) {
              ElementFacade sf = ElementFacade.getInstance();
              List<Element> list = sf.getElements(session.getUser());
              return Response.status(200)
                      .header(Endpoint.SESSION_TOKEN, session.getToken())
                      .entity(new GenericEntity<List<Element>>(list) {}).build();
          }
          return ResponseFactory.createResponse(403, 4006);
      } catch (InvalidTokenException e) {
          return ResponseFactory.createResponse(401, 4005);
      } catch (SessionTimeoutException e) {
          return ResponseFactory.createResponse(401, 4004);
      } catch (Throwable th) {
          log.error("", th);
          return ResponseFactory.createResponse(500, 5099);
      }
}
```

That's it... You only need to create a GenericEntity...

Comment: instead of all this, you could have a MessageContext object at class level and get the HttpServletResponse object from there. then set any status code you want and just return your list... the status code and headers will go along